# String literals and String which is acted upon intern() method will go in SCP area. Rest all in heap

Tags: java, arrays

`String literals` and `String` which is acted upon `intern()` method will go in `SCP area`. Rest all in heap.

If that is the case if i create

`String s = new String("apple");`

Obviously it will create one object in `heap`, my doubt is it will create "`apple`" in `SCP(String Constant Pool)` also. (Lets assume "apple" is not there in SCP).

What about `String[] arrays`?

Can you please elaborate in detail..

Comment: The String literal "apple" goes to the SCP. A String object with value "apple" will go into the Heap. So, totally 2 "apple"s

Answer (score 0):

`String` objects created with the new operator do not refer to objects in the string pool but can be made to using String’s `intern()` method. The `java.lang.String.intern()` returns an interned `String`, that is, one that has an entry in the global `String literal pool`. If the `String` is not already in the global `String literal pool`, then it will be added.

Each time your code create a string literal, the JVM checks the string literal pool first. If the string already exists in the pool, a reference to the pooled instance returns. If the string does not exist in the pool, a new String object instantiates, then is placed in the pool.

```
String[] stringArray = new String[] { "abc", "xyz" };
```

Executing this line there are two String literals created "`abc`" and "`xyz`" in `PERMGEN space`.

All objects, except `string literals`, are created on the heap. From `Java 7`, string literals are created on the `heap` as well.

Comment: You seem to be saying that there won't be an `"apple"` string in the SCP. That's incorrect.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder it will create in SCP

Comment: You should clarify your answer, then.

Answer (score 0):

> Obviously it will create one object in heap, my doubt is it will create `"apple"` in SCP(String Constant Pool) also. (Lets assume "apple" is not there in SCP).

Yes. When the class containing that code is loaded, `"apple"` will be added to the SCP if it's not already there. Then, later, when that line of code *executes*, a `String` object is created on the heap. The heap object will be different from the SCP object, but they'll both use the *same* underlying character array, as we can see from the Java 8 source:

```
public String(String original) {
    this.value = original.value;
    this.hash = original.hash;
}
```

or the Java 7 source:

```
public String(String original) {
    int size = original.count;
    char[] originalValue = original.value;
    char[] v;
    if (originalValue.length > size) {
        // The array representing the String is bigger than the new
        // String itself.  Perhaps this constructor is being called
        // in order to trim the baggage, so make a copy of the array.
        int off = original.offset;
        v = Arrays.copyOfRange(originalValue, off, off+size);
    } else {
        // The array representing the String is the same
        // size as the String, so no point in making a copy.
        v = originalValue;
    }
    this.offset = 0;
    this.count = size;
    this.value = v;
}
```

Since `"apple"` is in the SCP and its value length is the same as its size, the `else` is used and both end up using the same character array.

Comment: will this be same for String[] arrays also, and ArrayList<String> also?

Comment: @frq: There is no interning of arrays or lists, just strings. So if you have `String[] a = { "foo" };` you'll have a string in the SCP (because it's a literal) and an array referring to that string. If you have `String[] a = { new String("foo") };`, you'll have a string in the SCP, another string (referring to the same characters) not in the SCP, and an array referring to the second string. As you can see, having an array (or list) or not doesn't really relate to the SCP at all.

Comment: thanks for sharing information. this whole concept can we code and test?

Comment: my exact question is like: ArrayList al = new ArrayList<String>();
al.add("one");
al.add("two");

above "one" and "two" will go and store in scp? or it will store in heap. Lets suppose these two literals are not there in SCP

Comment: @frq: It's not "or," for a couple of versions now the SCP is in the heap. :-) In your example there, there will be a single instance of each string, and that instance will be in the SCP because you've used literals and haven't used `new` (you probably know this, but you almost **never** want to use `new String` -- and I've had people give me a hard time for including "almost" in that sentence :-) ). Note that strings in the SCP *can* be garbage collected if they're not referenced elsewhere, and in fact Java 8 adds new limits to keep the SCP from being over-large.